# How to deploy GeoServer on WildFly

Tags: geoserver, deployment

I was deploy geoserver.war using WildFly, it can be deploy but the unzip file will be shown at TMP folder. Is there any way to change the path and make it unzip to "deployments" file?

Answer (score 2):

If that you need is to change the data directory, you can configure this using this post.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html

On this section of the documentation of GeoServer, explained how to configure the data directory using another folder of your file system, you can establish the directory that you want to use.

If you deploy using standalone (my case), you cant add the JAVA_OPTS parameter on the file $WILDFLY_INSTALL/bin/standalone.conf.

```
-DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/folder/in/your/filesystem/geoserver/data
```

Comment: Can you add some more background about what the link details? Short link-only answers are likely to get deleted. Also links don't always last forever.

Comment: thanks @jbchurchill, I added some additional comments, i hope i have been clear.